# Symfony replace parameter variable in yaml file

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

Is it possible to replace a parameter within a yaml file, e.g.

```
 foo: '%logged_user%'
```

with the username of the currently logged user in symfony2?
What do i need to write therefore in parameters.yml ?

```
 logged_user: ???
```

Comment: For what purpose you want to replace a parameter within a `yml` file? Currently logged user can be retrieved in a controller with `$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();` or shortly with `$this->getUser();`. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#retrieving-the-user-object

Comment: For gaufrette directory path, i want to have a folder for each user:
directory: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/%user%/images  or directory: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/%user%/videos .. and the %user% should be the current logged in username.

Comment: Ok. I don't think you should enquiry through the parameters.yml or whatsoever. Can't you set up these data in other way? I'm no expert in SF2 so I'm afraid I can't help you more than that.

Comment: ok, no i need to set the directory in a config.yml file .. Anyone an idea ?

Comment: Um buddy no offense, but you dont need that. You have one codebase, one config.yml, so one logged_user global variable, and multiple users, how do you figure that's gonna work? :) What you need is maybe a table in your database, or a new field in your users table. But I'm pretty sure all that can be avoided by using D4V1D's first comment.

Comment: didn't get that one "so one logged_user global variable". I need to set the folder of Gaufrette file upload in my config.yml. . i already know how to retrieve the user within a controller but thats not what i need.